Forgiveness for Judas?
Judas, who betrayed Jesus Christ, repented (asked for forgiveness) for his betrayal. Jesus preached that he was willing to "forgive anyone who asks"!  Did Judas Ask?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Do you have a reference for "Judas asked for forgiveness"?

In writing this question, are you alluding to Matt 27:4?  That is not repentance nor a request for forgiveness.

The closest that Judas gets to "repentance" is his admission of guilt found in Matt 27:4 -

saying, “I have sinned by betraying innocent blood.” They said, “What
is that to us? See to it yourself.”

However, we must be careful to distinguish between a statement of fact, ie, an admission of guilt, and repentance.  Let me set these ideas out:
Confession and Admission
The Greek word involved is ὁμολογέω = to confess or agree.
Confession and admission of guilt is just that - a psychopath will readily admit to murder and be proud of it!  [Note - I am not suggesting Judas was psychopathic, far from it.  I say this to point out that confession is not repentance.]  However, confession is a necessary step before repentance!
Repentance
Here the Greek word is μετανοέω = literally a change of mind = repent.  Paul sums up the process involved in 2 Cor 7:10

Godly sorrow brings repentance that leads to salvation without regret,
but worldly sorrow brings death.

Note the difference - Judas betrayed innocent blood because he presumably thought that this might force Jesus to initiate His earthly kingdom.  However, this showed how Judas completely misunderstood the nature of Jesus' kingdom - a spiritual kingdom based on humility, loyalty and righteousness, not betrayal and lies.
Judas' plan failed and he greatly regretted his failure but not the attempt to be great in his misunderstood mission of Jesus.  Thus, he did not really want a humble part in Jesus' spiritual kingdom, but greatness in an earthly kingdom.
Thus, while there was confession of his failure, there was no repentance; Judas never approached Jesus for forgiveness (which Jesus was sure to have granted), and thus, was never forgiven.
The above conclusion is confirmed by the other effects of true repentance:

Acts 3:19 - Repent, then, and turn to God, so that your sins may be wiped out, that times of refreshing may come from the Lord
Acts 26:20 - First to those in Damascus, then to those in Jerusalem and in all Judea, and then to the Gentiles, I preached that they should repent and turn to God and demonstrate their repentance by their deeds.
Mark 1:15 - “The time has come,” he said. “The kingdom of God has come near. Repent and believe the good news!”
Luke 3:8 - Produce fruit in keeping with repentance. And do not begin to say to yourselves, ‘We have Abraham as our father.’ For I tell you that out of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham.
Luke 13:5 - No, I tell you; but unless you repent, you will all likewise perish.”


This remedies the OP's assertion that Judas repents - but does his qualification of Jesus' blood as innocent "ἀθῷον" offer some hope that his conscience is engaged, or that he is starting a process? It perhaps contrasts with Pilate's self-description "Ἀθῷός εἰμι". The Pharisees call Jesus guilty. Pilate calls himself innocent. Judas has the pieces of the jigsaw. And "see to it yourself" suggests he might see to it. They think he wants to.

Both Judas and Peter betrayed Christ and realized their mistake.  Judas could not forgive himself and did not seek forgiveness, but instead quickly and preemptively judged himself.  Peter did not dissociate from the fellowship, and returned to follow, despite his shortcomings.
[Isa 44:22 NIV] I have swept away your offenses like a cloud, your sins like the morning mist. Return to me, for I have redeemed you."
